# $[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha,\beta)$:$ \mathbb{F}_{p}]=\text{lcm}(m,n) $ and $[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha)∩\mathbb{F}_{p}(\beta)$:$ \mathbb{F}_{p}]=\gcd(m,n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory

My grammar can be awkward because my native language is not English. Please excuse me.

> [*Problem*]
>   There are $ \alpha, \beta\in K$ that is a field extension of $ \mathbb{F}_{p}$ such 
>   that $[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha): \mathbb{F}_{p}]=12,[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\beta): \mathbb{F}_{p}]=20 $.
>   Show that $[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha,\beta): \mathbb{F}_{p}]=60 $ and $[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha)∩\mathbb{F}_{p}(\beta): \mathbb{F}_{p}]=4$.

Let $ G(\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha,\beta)/\mathbb{F}_{p})=(\phi)$ where $ \phi$ : $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha,\beta)\to\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha,\beta)$, $ \phi(u)=u^{p}$ and order of $ {\phi}$ be $n$.
Then there exists $d|n$ such that $G(\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha)/\mathbb{F}_{p})=(\phi^{d})$.
so $12=[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_{p}]=[(\phi):(\phi^{d})]=\frac{n}{n/d}=d$.
Similarly we can show that $G(\mathbb{F}_{p}(\beta)/\mathbb{F}_{p})=(\phi^{20})$.
I think that $G(\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha)∩\mathbb{F}_{p}(\beta)/\mathbb{F}_{p})$ is smallest group containing $(\phi^{12})$ and $ (\phi^{20})$, that is $(\phi^{4})$ , and $G(\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha,\beta)/\mathbb{F}_{p})=(\phi^{12})∩(\phi^{20})=(\phi^{60})$, but I don't know the exact reason.
Further on if $[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha): \mathbb{F}_{p}]=m,[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\beta): \mathbb{F}_{p}]=n $. Then $[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha,\beta): \mathbb{F}_{p}]=\text{lcm}(m,n) $ and $[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha)∩\mathbb{F}_{p}(\beta): \mathbb{F}_{p}]=\gcd(m,n)$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yikes is this unreadable. Too many symbols in too little space. Please use `$$...$$` to put longer strings of equations in display mode.

Comment: Also generally, $\Bbb{F}_p$ or $\Bbb{Z}/(p)$ or $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ is preferable to $\Bbb{Z}_p$ to denote the field with $p$ elements, ($p$ prime) since $\Bbb{Z}_p$ conflicts with notation for the $p$-adic integers. (And it looks pretty weird here when you're used to seeing it mean the $p$-adics. XP)

Comment: oh sorry.. I'll correct it.

Comment: This is not really different to saying the Galois group is cyclic generated by the Frobenius but any extension $K/\Bbb{F}_p$ of degree $n$ is the smallest field containing a primitive $p^n-1$ root of $1$, and those primitive roots behave well under compositum and intersection. Your notation doesn't make it clear : the Galois group is $\phi^{\Bbb{Z}/n \Bbb{Z}}$ the largest group which is a quotient group of $\phi^{\Bbb{Z}/n \Bbb{Z}},\phi^{\Bbb{Z}/m \Bbb{Z}}$ is $\phi^{\Bbb{Z}/\gcd(n,m) \Bbb{Z}}$ and the smallest group containing them as quotients is $\phi^{\Bbb{Z}/lcm(n,m) \Bbb{Z}}$